# Floated div to fill remainder space

Tags: html, css, css-float, fill-parent

I have a CodePen for this set up here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Isqou

```
div.linksBox {
border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
background:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
margin:0 12px 12px 0;

text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="topFloats" style="margin-top:5px; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid black; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div style="width:20px; height:340px; float:left; background-color:red;"></div>
    <div id="rightFloatWrapper" class="linksBox">
        <div class="rollover linkIconLayout" id="" style='width: 134px; height: 122px; background-color:green;' href=""></div>
        <div class="rollover linkIconLayout" id="" style='width: 142px; height: 112px; background-color:blue;' href=""</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An image in the red (left) floated div sets the height of the black-bordered div.  I need an inner (drop-shadowed) div (whose minimum dimensions are set by the size of it's content divs) to expand to fill the remainder of the space in the black-bordered div.

I was able to fill the horizontal space by taking float off the drop-shadowed div, adding an overflow, and setting the margins to accommodate the drop-shadow.  How can I fill the remaining vertical space?

Comment: You can look into [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Otherwise you likely have to use set widths or javascript

Comment: Thanks @zach!  I need to support IE 9 so I guess I'll have to use JavaScript.  Though there might be a way to do it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  I [ended up](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bcinr) abandoning floats and using `position:absolute;right:0; bottom:0;top:0;` on the inner (drop-shadowed) div.  The trick was to use a `right:5%` and set the (previously floated) red div width to the same (`width:5%`).  This accomplished what I was attempting to do with the floated divs and still keeps the flexibility of a liquid layout (with the small downside that if I change the width, I need to make sure to change the `right:`property as well).

Hopefully this will help someone else that tries this.

Cheers!